# simulating tail -f in Perl

Tags: perl

As per [solution provided in perldoc](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-do-a-tail--f-in-perl-), I am trying to emulate `tail -f` but it's not working as expected. The below code could print all lines first time but not the newly lines appended. Could you please elaborate if I am missing any thing here.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (LOGFILE, "aa") or die "could not open file reason $! \n";

for (;;)
{
        seek(LOGFILE,0,1);  ### clear OF condition        
        for ($curpos = tell(LOGFILE); <LOGFILE>; $curpos = tell(LOGFILE)) 
        {
                print "$_ \n";
        }

        sleep 1;
        seek(LOGFILE,$curpos,0); ### Setting cursor at the EOF
}
```

Comment: aa is the file name on which is continuously growing and I need to do tail -f aa.

Comment: See also [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Tail)

Answer (score 1):

works fine for me. How are you updating `"aa"` ? 
You wont see the data immediately if it is a `buffered` write to `"aa"`.
can you try the following in a different terminal and check whether you are seeing any update.

```
while ( 1 )
echo "test" >> aa
end
```

If you are using perl to update `aa`, check [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_13.htm) section on buffering and how to disable.

Comment: If I add lines using vi editor it is not working. while echo "test" >> aa does work.

Comment: then you are probably [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).

Comment: what about `tail -f aa` when you use vi ? Are you seeing different behaviour with `tail -f "aa"` and your script when you use `vi` to update `"aa"` ?

Comment: When editing vi probably doesn't write to the same file. I'd guess it writes to a temporary file and then deletes the old one and renames the temporary one. Because your script has the old file still open the old file will remain (but not appear in directory listings). If you want to detect file *replacement* then you'll want to loop running "stat" on the file and look for changes in size/timestamps. Then open it, read whatever you want and close the file again.

Comment: Thanks Richard for the explaining the anomaly.